# Find missing number in an array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

A friend of mine asked this question long time ago. He asked me to this without iterating the array. I had in my mind to find the sum on N number as then subtract from it the sum of array numbers. and another the XOR calculation.
But these solutions still needs to iterate the array.
I wounder if there exists such solution or algorithm to do this without iterating the array.
Also if you are going to flag this question duplicate please refer me the link.

Comment: Plz provide an example

Comment: Without iterating over the array, you cannot know what's in it.

Comment: for e.g. i have an array [1,2,4,5,7,8, 9, 10] and I know the numbers can be from 1-10 but 1 number is missing, So need to find out missing 6 form the array.

Comment: (Lose that friend (as you lost at least one word in `asked me to this`).) Without further restrictions, it should be possible to prove this impossible (try to use contradiction). One such restrictions would be _numbers from_ `0` _to_ `n` _in an_ `n` _element array in `ascending order`_.

Comment: You can always divide the array into it's first item and rest items like `.slice(0,1)` and `.slice(1)` in JS or `head` and `tail` in Haskell and feed the rest as a new array to the same function recursively. While this is a quasi iteration, as you will be working with separate arrays all the time, you might be able to fool your friend.

Comment: You didn't really think about the problem, did you ?

Answer (score 3):

What's the missing number in this array ?

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, *
```

(The `*` stands for a number you are not allowed to read, otherwise that would be iterating.)

Comment: This **is** an answer.

Comment: yes, thanks. this was the answer i was looking for. no such solution exists without iterating over the array.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a missing number in an array you have to inspect it, meaning iterate of the array. No way to do th is without iterating.

Answer (score 0):

In general case, you can't do this. Imagine, that you're given Yves Daoust's sample:

```
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ?]
```

and you're allowed to read *any* items of the array, but the last one. What is it? Do I hear *seven*? No, that's a typical wrong solution:

```
item = i + (i-1)*(i-2)*(i-3)*(i-4)*(i-5)*(i-6)*F(i)
```

where `F(i)` is an arbitrary function (well, not arbitrary, there're some loose restrictions, however - `F(i)` can't be, say `1/(i-3)`). Let

```
F(i) == 0           -> last item ==   7 
F(i) == 1           -> last item == 727
F(i) == (pi-i)/720  -> last item ==  pi
...
```

You have to have more restrictions, e.g. array represents values of a polynom of the least possible power; in that case the solution is `7`